# How to set GNUMAKE variable for ndk-build to work

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I am trying to make ndk-build to work within Cygwin on windows. As per the NDK documentation (specifically INSTALL.htm), *"The NDK requires GNU Make 3.81 or later being available on your development."*

I have Gnu Make installed on my computer.

So far, so good.

Within Cygwin bash, I cd over to the android NDK root directory. Now when I type in the following command (without parameters right now, just to see if the command works):

*$./ndk-build*
**ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.**

So I try to set the GNUMAKE variable, but no luck:

*$export GNUMAKE='/cygdrive/c\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin'*
**ERROR: Your GNUMAKE variable is defined to an invalid name: /cygdrive/c\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin
Please fix it to point to a valid make executable (e.g. usr/bin/make)**

I even tried setting it to usr/bin/make as it suggests, but same invalid name error.

Anyone, knows how to resolve this?

I'm using Windows 7, NDK r5, Cygwin 1.7.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had an issue with GNUMake when putting the ndk in a folder with a space in it (I originally put it in the program files directory). I moved everything to C:/android/android-ndk and C:/android/android-sdk and updated my path settings to include these directories.

Comment: Android tools sometimes have problems with spaces in path names. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic error. It means there was a problem somehow with the make command, but the error message itself is hidden. To help diagnose the problem, open your ndk_build script in the ndk directory, and change these lines:

```
ABS_GNUMAKE=`which $GNUMAKE 2> /dev/null`
...
GNUMAKE=`which make 2> /dev/null`
```

to these:

```
ABS_GNUMAKE=`which $GNUMAKE`
...
GNUMAKE=`which make`
```

And then you will get a more detailed error message. Note that it might not even be a problem with the 'make' command, it might be a problem with the 'which' command. Make sure you have cygwin installed.

Answer (score 1):

Its not problem with the make but installing cygwin
in ndk-demo script the make path is found using which command mostly which command 
installation is missing in cygwin.

Solution:
Relaunch your cygwin installation select utils (install )

Checking:
$ which make 
should give you the make command path on cygwin prompt.

Regards,
Vasu

Answer (score 1):

delete Environmental variable GNUMAKE 
close the cygwin terminal
open again cygwin terminal... go the path where u want to build.. and now build it...
I am sure hopefully you will build successfully..as i do..

Answer (score 0):

The answer with moving NDK to a directory without spaces is definitely right. After that you will probably able to run ndk-build from the Cygwin shell.
However running ndk-build from Windows commmand line (like "bash ndk-build") will probably cause the same queer error with "incorrect GNU make".
It is reproducible with NDK 6b as well.
And I hope it is fixed in the newest version of NDK...

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
>   or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.

While trying to install Cygwin i missed out to install MAKE PACKAGE

Just need to **search make in the Search box and it will shows the Branches that includes devel branch** and from devel branch i selected make package.

That's all issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i worked hard on error in gygwin terminal "gnumake variable is define to invalid name" and after that i get to the point that we simply remove this error by deleting the GNUMAKE path in environment variable both in system and user variable if u created it hope its helps....

mycomputer > system properties > advanced system setting > environment variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem here  is the name of the GNUMAKE variable.The name given was

`/cygdrive/c\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin` change it into `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/GnuWin32/bin/make`

only use forword Slash .Sometime the space in the folder structure does not taken

Happy coding.